# Backbone Routing + URL Rewrite in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js, pushstate, backbone-routing

I've encountered a peculiar issue when dealing with Backbone routing.

Our app is being hosted in `example.com/photo/index.php`, and we'd like to hook an event on it which when triggered, appear in the address bar as `example.com/photo/<ID>`. Below is how we set up our rewrite rule androuter settings:

```
RewriteRule ^/photo/([0-9]+)?$ /photo/index.php/photo/$1 [L]
```

**Inside Backbone.Router.extend:**

```
routes: {
    'photo/:ID': 'viewPhoto'
},
```

**After router has been instantiated:**

```
$(function() {
    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: 'pushState' in window.history,
        root: '/'
    });
});
```

This works great in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, but in IE9 you have to access the event hook with `example.com/photo/#photo/<ID>`, which is not very cool.

So we tried toggling the pushState option on (`pushState: true`) and hope it could help, but now whenever accessing `example.com/photo/<ID>` in IE9, page will be redirected to `example.com/#photo/<ID>` instead, and actually displaying the content of `example.com/index.php`.

I suppose (?) this can be a non-issue if we change the event hooking URL to something like `example.com/photo/view/<ID>`, however we can't touch that part.

Is there anyway to make either `example.com/photo/<ID>`, `example.com/#photo/<ID>`, or `example.com/photo/#<ID>` working as expected under IE9, with or without pushState?